# give aws s3 read permission to fargate cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I create a AWS fargate cluster

now I changed the docker image so to read input data from s3.
in the developer stage I passed the credentials through enviromental variables and the container worked

now on AWS I think I am supposed to add a policy

i first create a role with

```
iam_role='ecsTaskExecutionRole'
aws iam wait role-exists --role-name $iam_role 2>/dev/null || \ aws iam --region $REGION create-role --role-name $iam_role \
  --assume-role-policy-document file://task-execution-assume-role.json || return 1
 

aws iam --region $REGION attach-role-policy --role-name $iam_role \
  --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy || return 1
```

where the Json file that I pass contains only:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  }
```

then I create another role that should be the task role to give the container the ability to read from S3

```
aws iam wait role-exists --role-name $task_role 2>/dev/null || \ 
aws iam --region $REGION create-role --role-name $task_role \
  --assume-role-policy-document file://task-role.json || return 1


aws iam --region $REGION attach-role-policy --role-name $task_role \
  --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess || return 1
```

in this case the json that I pass is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

and when I create the service I pass also an ecs-params.yml file

```
version: 1
task_definition:
  task_role_arn: ${task_role}
  task_execution_role: ${task_execution_role}
  ecs_network_mode: awsvpc
  task_size:
    mem_limit: 0.5GB
    cpu_limit: 256
run_params:
  network_configuration:
    awsvpc_configuration:
      subnets:
        - ${subnet1}
        - ${subnet2}
      security_groups:
        - ${secgroupid}
      assign_public_ip: ENABLED
```

the error I get is:

INFO[0016] (service dashboard) failed to launch a task with (error ECS was unable to assume the role 'arn:aws:iam::accountID:role/dashboard_role' that was provided for this task. Please verify that the role being passed has the proper trust relationship and permissions and that your IAM user has permissions to pass this role.).  timestamp="2021-03-04 12:13:23 +0000 UTC"

what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two IAM roles you can assign to an ECS Fargate task. The ["Task Execution Role"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html) which allows the ECS to deploy your Fargate task, and the ["Task Role"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html), which allows code running inside your container to make calls to the AWS API.

Check that you have a Task Role assigned to your Fargate task definition, in addition to the Task Execution Role, and add the S3 permissions to the Task Role instead of the Task Execution Role.

Comment: I edited the question to incorporate your suggestions. still errors

Comment: @bruvio is `dashboard_role` the name of the task role? You haven't properly created that role. The `Service` in that `sts:AssumeRole` statement should be `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com` just like the other role.

Comment: that worked. so the task role has to be added as well as trusted and then I can add all the policies I want. good